# PayPal API CSP preventing SDK from loading

Tags: asp.net-core, paypal, content-security-policy, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to use PayPals API integration on my website, however whenever I try to load the page I get the "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive" error so nothing on the page actually loads, I have security headers in place in `Program.cs` with `app.UseSecurityHeaders(policyCollection);` where I reduced `policyCollection` down to

```
var policyCollection = new HeaderPolicyCollection()
  .AddContentSecurityPolicy(policy =>
  {  
    policy.AddDefaultSrc()
    .Self()
    .From(allowedUris)
  };
```

And where `allowedUris` is a list of URIs, including `"https://paypal.com"`, but regardless of what I do I can't get any of the PayPal resources to load, does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong here?

Edit:
Chrome Console Logs
[image: Chrome Console Logs]

Edit 2 PayPal Response CSP style snippet:

`style-src 'self' https://*.paypal.com:* https://*.paypalobjects.com 'unsafe-inline';`

Comment: Have you checked PayPal's CSP?

Comment: @Dai can you elaborate on what you mean by that please?

Comment: What CSP headers are PayPal putting in their own responses? You'll see them in your browser's DevTools.

Comment: Also, please show all relevant messages from your browser's console.

Comment: I've added them to the post

Answer (score 0):

According to the error messages there are no violation of URIs, they are all inline style and script. These could be embedded by some scripts. Check the sources in the console. If a few static references are used it could make sense to add the hashes for them. Otherwise you might have to replace or rewrite the code. If this doesn't work you might have to accept adding 'unsafe-inline' to script-src and style-src. Even though this is not ideal, it is better than no CSP, especially if you lock down all fetch directives.